# How can i stop a Discord bot without stopping the music?

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I have a public discord bot that is more than 700 servers and is used by 165k users.
The bot has music integrated, so people can listen music via Discord using the bot.
When i have to restart the bot to update something it will leave the voice channels. Is there a way to restart it without the bot leaving the channel so that when I restart it the music stops for a couple of seconds and then resumes?
The bot is made in java (JDA)

I haven't really tried something. I was thinking of starting it in debug mode and maybe "reload" it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to keep the bot Online the whole time.
My 1st idea would be to host the bot on your local machine untill the bot restarts ( don't know if this would work though ), my guess is that it would have to work on the exact same JDA object.

My 2nd idea i that you could store all the information about what channels the bot was on, what music it was playing etc. and then retrieve it in an onReady() event. This will still make the bot leave the channels, but it will join them again after restart...

You could also come up with something that combines theese two ideas i guess.